# Change date format within the text of a html tag or its children (and not their attributes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in need of reformatting some dates using javascript. My initial attempt was this:

```js
var re = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g;
$('.container td').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(re, '$3-$2-$1'));
});
```

but it also (naturally) changed dates within the html tag of any children (like the 'value' attribute). How can I reformat this to only check text outside of any tag?

Answer (score 1):

Use text() instead of html()

```
var re = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g;
$('.container td').each(function() {
  var tdText = $(this).text;
  //Only repleace the match element
  if(tdText.match(re)){
      $(this).text(tdText.replace(re, '$3-$2-$1'));
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that this strips the content of all HTML tags. E.g. `<td> Text <a href="#top">link</a></td>` becomes `<td> Text link </td>`

Comment: Check my updated answer. Now we only replace the text of matched elements.